# Finding the orthognal complement of a subspace

Tags: orthogonality

Suppose I am looking at a subspace $U$ of $V=R^n$ (equipped with the standard dot product) with

$$
U = \\{ (x_1 ... x_n) \in V | x_1+x_2+...+x_n = 0\\}
$$

Now I want to find the orthogonal complement of U. So all vectors $v\in R^n$ that satisfy

$$\begin{align} 
<v,x>&=0, \forall x \in U    \\\\\\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i x_i = 0 
\end{align}$$

Now I see that for all vectors $x$ where $x_1=x_2=...=x_n$ the above equation is satisfied. However, I don't really know how to go about finding all orthogonal vectors. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: You've found a subspace of the orthogonal and you should be able to compute the dimension of this subspace. See if you can compute the dimension of the orthogonal.

Comment: ok let's call my new subspace W. Shouldnt dim(W) be 1? I can form all vectors in W by multiplying any vector where all components match with a scalar. 
For the dimension of the orthogonal I don't really have any ideas though..

Comment: Good for the dimension of W. In fact, it's generated by the vector $(1,\ldots,1)$. Do you know of a relation between the dimension of a subspace and the dimension of its orthogonal? If so, it then suffices to get the dimension of $U$. To do this, it could be helpful to write it as the kernel of a linear map.

Comment: I just found that we did proof (for finite vector spaces) dim(U) + dim(U_compl)=dim(V). I assume thats what you were hinting at. However, im struggeling with finding the dimension of U. I would need to find a base for U first, wouldnt I?

Comment: You don't need to (at least not explicitly). If you write $U$ as the kernel of a linear map $f$, then $n=rk(f)+d$ where d is the kernel of $f$. Usually, this is done with $f$ a linear form because the rank is easy to compute for such a map.

Comment: I think I found another way. I did find a base for U which tells me that $dim(U)=n-1$. Using the above this means that $dim(U^{\perp})=1$ and thus I should be done :)

Comment: Yes, finding a basis is also possible in this case, I was simply lazier than that! In fact, $U$ is the kernel of the linear form sending $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ to $\sum x_i$ which is non-zero, hence of rank one.